# Where to put non-member function definition of a PRIVATE nested (inner)class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inner-classes

Following is a simple example of my actual problem. I have a non-member function defined using
     `friend` keyword in the `InnerClass`. The definition of this function should be outside of `InnerClass`.

On the other hand, the class definition is under `private` of `MyClass` as I want to use the `InnerClass` specifically for `MyClass`.

In this case, **where I can actually put the definition of `friend` function?**

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
    class InnerClass
    {
        int m_int;
    public:
        InnerClass(int i) :m_int(i) {}

        // non-member (friend) function, for which I need a definition outside the class!
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const InnerClass &obj);
    };
    // ERROR: too many parameter for this operator
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const InnerClass &obj)
    {
        return output << obj.m_int << " ";
    }

private:
    InnerClass m_innerClass;

public:
    explicit MyClass(int i) : m_innerClass{ i } {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const MyClass &obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const MyClass &obj)
{
    output << obj.m_innerClass << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    MyClass classObj{ 2 };
    std::cout << classObj;
    return 0;
}
```

The error msg:

```
  \main.cpp(27): error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters
  \main.cpp(27): error C2333: 'MyClass::operator <<': error in function declaration; skipping function body
```

Comment: note that the one you declared as `friend` is a free function, the one you defined is a member function, the answer shows you how to define the free function inside the class

Comment: @user463035818 and is that the **only way** of doing, **in above-mentioned situations** ?

Comment: there is always more than one way, not sure what you mean...

Comment: My doubt is: why `operator<<` of `InnerClass` did not found the its definition right after `InnerClass` definition?

Comment: ...because you didnt supply a definition of that operator, what you did supply is a member function of `MyClass` that is a bit similar to the operator you want, but its not the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actualy define friend non-member functions right inside the class definition.

Here's your code snippet fixed:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
    class InnerClass
    {
        int m_int;
    public:
        InnerClass(int i) :m_int(i) {}

        // non-member (friend) function, which we can define right here
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const InnerClass &obj)
        {
            return output << obj.m_int << " ";
        }
    };    

private:
    InnerClass m_innerClass;

public:
    explicit MyClass(int i) : m_innerClass{ i } {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const MyClass &obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const MyClass &obj)
{
   return output << obj.m_innerClass << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    MyClass classObj{ 2 };
    std::cout << classObj;
    return 0;
}
```

You could do the same with the other `operator<<`.

Now, if `InnerClass` weren't private, you could still define the function at the global scope, but you'd need to fully qualify second parameter's name:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const MyClass::InnerClass &obj)
{                                                //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    return output << obj.m_int << " ";
}
```

Comment: and is that the **only way** of doing, **in above-mentioned situations** ? and why `operator<<` did not found the definition right after `InnerClass` definition?

Comment: @Const the compiler did find the definition, but as I mentioned above, you defined a different method than the one you declared as friend

Comment: @user463035818 Hmm okay.

Comment: @Const Yeah, what that user said. Consider [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f70044848f185f9). The error in your original code is because member operators can only have 1 parameter.

Comment: You could still define the functions outside if you make the name of `InnerClass` accessible: [example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/974f7c533034e21c)

Comment: @jrok This `typedef InnerClass Detail;` is a great idea, which I missed. If you want, you can add it as an alternative solution to your answer. Looks promising to my needs. Thanks!